# php - replace string occurrences

Tags: php, string

I have a string `"First line  | second line | third line"`
How can I replace `|` with a  `new line` character?

I'm trying to use `preg_replace` but with no liuck

Answer (score 26, accepted):

here it is

```
str_replace('|',"\n",$string);
```

when \n is placed in double qouted string it changes to a new line

Answer (score 11):

Use this:

```
str_replace('|', PHP_EOL, $str);
```

You should use `PHP_EOL` instead of `"\n"` because PHP_EOL will always work on all server platforms. (NB. Windows uses `"\r\n"` and unix/linux uses `"\n"`).

Answer (score 3):

Using `strtr` is a tad faster than `str_replace` or `preg_replace`.

```
echo strtr($string,'|', "\n");
```

Mind the double quotes around the `\n`.

Also, if you want to output HTML, a newline char is not sufficient, you need to replace it with `<br />` tags.

```
echo str_replace("|", "<br />\n", $string);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is more generic case where e.g.  '' serves as replacwment string:

```
//  Provides: Hll Wrld f PHP
$vowels = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u", "A", "E", "I", "O", "U"];
$onlyconsonants = str_replace($vowels, "", "Hello World of PHP");
```